# association stopped working after seeding data in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

### What are you doing?

I have many to many relationship between User and Routes, and User and Books. I created some seeder data to populate my database. And I was able to find User and include ROUTEs and BOOKs. 
IF I do not seed the database, everything still work. I just manually POST all the relationships and associations with POSTMAN. I can find User by ID and it includes its ROUTEs and BOOKs.
The problem comes in when I try to do both. After seeding the data, I cannot seem to set any associations afterward using POSTMAN.

I dont really know which part of the code should I be putting here since I have no idea what is causing the problem. But here is the repo(branch test): https://github.com/leogoesger/gutsy-api

This is what i get just doing migration without seeding:
`js
{
    "id": 1,
    "role": "ADMIN",
    "firstName": "Leo",
    "middleName": "",
    "lastName": "Qiu",
    "email": "leoq91@gmail.commm",
    "password": "$2a$10$a/Rv18tGFr1MgxcJkrd0aewo9lJXUxbNJMiq4.cIuWUOq0fSp.Uju",
    "address1": "319 I st",
    "address2": "",
    "city": "Davis",
    "zip": "95616",
    "isVerified": false,
    "createdAt": "2017-11-22T02:33:23.425Z",
    "updatedAt": "2017-11-22T02:33:23.425Z",
    "routes": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "The Cave Route",
            "description": "Ice cave",
            "grade": "V10",
            "category": "Boulder",
            "open": true,
            "createdAt": "2017-11-22T02:38:32.024Z",
            "updatedAt": "2017-11-22T02:38:32.024Z",
            "areaId": 1,
            "UserRoute": {
                "id": 1,
                "userId": 1,
                "routeId": 1,
                "createdAt": "2017-11-22T02:38:34.316Z",
                "updatedAt": "2017-11-22T02:38:34.316Z"
            }
        }
    ],
    "books": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "The good, the great and the awesome",
            "description": "A cool book about High Sierra!",
            "price": "39.99",
            "createdAt": "2017-11-22T02:38:29.313Z",
            "updatedAt": "2017-11-22T02:38:29.313Z",
            "UserBook": {
                "id": 1,
                "userId": 1,
                "bookId": 1,
                "createdAt": "2017-11-22T02:38:36.970Z",
                "updatedAt": "2017-11-22T02:38:36.970Z"
            }
        }
    ]
}`

This is what i get just doing migration with seeding. I can see all the associations in the DB. 
`js
{
    "id": 3,
    "role": "ADMIN",
    "firstName": "Leo",
    "middleName": "",
    "lastName": "Qiu",
    "email": "leoq91@gmail.commm",
    "password": "$2a$10$a/Rv18tGFr1MgxcJkrd0aewo9lJXUxbNJMiq4.cIuWUOq0fSp.Uju",
    "address1": "319 I st",
    "address2": "",
    "city": "Davis",
    "zip": "95616",
    "isVerified": false,
    "createdAt": "2017-11-22T02:33:23.425Z",
    "updatedAt": "2017-11-22T02:33:23.425Z",
    "routes": [ ],
    "books": [ ]
}`

### What do you expect to happen?

Well, I want to get my routes and books data associated to User.

### What is actually happening?

Nothing is coming back

*Output, either JSON or SQL*

**Dialect: postgres 9.6
__Dialect version:** XXX
**Database version:** XXX
**Sequelize version:** XXX
**Tested with master branch:** No

**Note :** *Your issue may be ignored by maintainers if it's not tested against `master` branch OR does not follow issue template.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embrassing!

`User.belongsToMany(Project, { as: 'Tasks', through: 'worker_tasks', foreignKey: 'userId' })
Project.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'Workers', through: 'worker_tasks', foreignKey: 'projectId' })`

Above is how I suppose to set it up

but i did the following:

`User.belongsToMany(Project, { as: 'Tasks', through: 'worker_tasks', foreignKey: 'projectId' })
Project.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'Workers', through: 'worker_tasks', foreignKey: 'userId' })`